# Boost compilation error

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,

I've been having issues with compilation errors where I've been getting this wall of errors:

```
/usr/include/boost/bind/bind.hpp: In instantiation of ‘void boost::_bi::list2<A1, A2>::operator()(boost::_bi::type<void>, F&, A&, int) [with F = void (*)(const boost::shared_ptr<const sensor_msgs::Imu_<st
d::allocator<void> > >&, const boost::shared_ptr<const sensor_msgs::NavSatFix_<std::allocator<void> > >&); A = boost::_bi::rrlist9<const boost::shared_ptr<const sensor_msgs::NavSatFix_<std::allocator<void
> > >&, const boost::shared_ptr<const sensor_msgs::Imu_<std::allocator<void> > >&, const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&, const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&, con
st boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&, const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&, const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&, const boost::shared_ptr<const 
message_filters::NullType>&, const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&>; A1 = boost::arg<1>; A2 = boost::arg<2>]’:                                                                          
/usr/include/boost/bind/bind.hpp:1402:50:   required from ‘boost::_bi::bind_t<R, F, L>::result_type boost::_bi::bind_t<R, F, L>::operator()(A1&&, A2&&, A3&&, A4&&, A5&&, A6&&, A7&&, A8&&, A9&&) [with A1 =
 const boost::shared_ptr<const sensor_msgs::NavSatFix_<std::allocator<void> > >&; A2 = const boost::shared_ptr<const sensor_msgs::Imu_<std::allocator<void> > >&; A3 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message
_filters::NullType>&; A4 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&; A5 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&; A6 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::Nu
llType>&; A7 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&; A8 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&; A9 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&; R 
= void; F = void (*)(const boost::shared_ptr<const sensor_msgs::Imu_<std::allocator<void> > >&, const boost::shared_ptr<const sensor_msgs::NavSatFix_<std::allocator<void> > >&); L = boost::_bi::list2<boos
t::arg<1>, boost::arg<2> >; boost::_bi::bind_t<R, F, L>::result_type = void]’                                                                                                                               
/usr/include/boost/bind/bind.hpp:833:35:   required from ‘void boost::_bi::list9<A1, A2, A3, A4, A5, A6, A7, A8, A9>::operator()(boost::_bi::type<void>, F&, A&, int) [with F = boost::_bi::bind_t<void, voi
d (*)(const boost::shared_ptr<const sensor_msgs::Imu_<std::allocator<void> > >&, const boost::shared_ptr<const sensor_msgs::NavSatFix_<std::allocator<void> > >&), boost::_bi::list2<boost::arg<1>, boost::a
rg<2> > >; A = boost::_bi::rrlist9<const boost::shared_ptr<const sensor_msgs::NavSatFix_<std::allocator<void> > >&, const boost::shared_ptr<const sensor_msgs::Imu_<std::allocator<void> > >&, const boost::
shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&, const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&, const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&, const boost::shared_ptr<const message_fi
lters::NullType>&, const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&, const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&, const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&>; A1 = bo
ost::arg<1>; A2 = boost::arg<2>; A3 = boost::arg<3>; A4 = boost::arg<4>; A5 = boost::arg<5>; A6 = boost::arg<6>; A7 = boost::arg<7>; A8 = boost::arg<8>; A9 = boost::arg<9>]’                               
/usr/include/boost/bind/bind.hpp:1402:50:   required from ‘boost::_bi::bind_t<R, F, L>::result_type boost::_bi::bind_t<R, F, L>::operator()(A1&&, A2&&, A3&&, A4&&, A5&&, A6&&, A7&&, A8&&, A9&&) [with A1 =
 const boost::shared_ptr<const sensor_msgs::NavSatFix_<std::allocator<void> > >&; A2 = const boost::shared_ptr<const sensor_msgs::Imu_<std::allocator<void> > >&; A3 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message
_filters::NullType>&; A4 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&; A5 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&; A6 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::Nu
llType>&; A7 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&; A8 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&; A9 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&; R 
= boost::_bi::unspecified; F = boost::_bi::bind_t<void, void (*)(const boost::shared_ptr<const sensor_msgs::Imu_<std::allocator<void> > >&, const boost::shared_ptr<const sensor_msgs::NavSatFix_<std::alloc
ator<void> > >&), boost::_bi::list2<boost::arg<1>, boost::arg<2> > >; L = boost::_bi::list9<boost::arg<1>, boost::arg<2>, boost::arg<3>, boost::arg<4>, boost::arg<5>, boost::arg<6>, boost::arg<7>, boost::
arg<8>, boost::arg<9> >; boost::_bi::bind_t<R, F, L>::result_type = void]’                           
/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:159:11:   required from ‘static void boost::detail::function::void_function_obj_invoker9<FunctionObj, R, T0, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8>::invoke(boost
::detail::function::function_buffer&, T0, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8) [with FunctionObj = boost::_bi::bind_t<boost::_bi::unspecified, boost::_bi::bind_t<void, void (*)(const boost::shared_ptr<const se
nsor_msgs::Imu_<std::allocator<void> > >&, const boost::shared_ptr<const sensor_msgs::NavSatFix_<std::allocator<void> > >&), boost::_bi::list2<boost::arg<1>, boost::arg<2> > >, boost::_bi::list9<boost::ar
g<1>, boost::arg<2>, boost::arg<3>, boost::arg<4>, boost::arg<5>, boost::arg<6>, boost::arg<7>, boost::arg<8>, boost::arg<9> > >; R = void; T0 = const boost::shared_ptr<const sensor_msgs::NavSatFix_<std::
allocator<void> > >&; T1 = const boost::shared_ptr<const sensor_msgs::Imu_<std::allocator<void> > >&; T2 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&; T3 = const boost::shared_ptr<const mes
sage_filters::NullType>&; T4 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&; T5 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&; T6 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters
::NullType>&; T7 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&; T8 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&]’
/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:936:38:   required from ‘void boost::function9<R, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9>::assign_to(Functor) [with Functor = boost::_bi::bind_t<boost::_bi::u
nspecified, boost::_bi::bind_t<void, void (*)(const boost::shared_ptr<const sensor_msgs::Imu_<std::allocator<void> > >&, const boost::shared_ptr<const sensor_msgs::NavSatFix_<std::allocator<void> > >&), b
oost::_bi::list2<boost::arg<1>, boost::arg<2> > >, boost::_bi::list9<boost::arg<1>, boost::arg<2>, boost::arg<3>, boost::arg<4>, boost::arg<5>, boost::arg<6>, boost::arg<7>, boost::arg<8>, boost::arg<9> >
 >; R = void; T0 = const boost::shared_ptr<const sensor_msgs::NavSatFix_<std::allocator<void> > >&; T1 = const boost::shared_ptr<const sensor_msgs::Imu_<std::allocator<void> > >&; T2 = const boost::shared
_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&; T3 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&; T4 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&; T5 = const boost::shared_ptr<const m
essage_filters::NullType>&; T6 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&; T7 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&; T8 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filte
rs::NullType>&]’                                                                                     
/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:727:7:   required from ‘boost::function9<R, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9>::function9(Functor, typename boost::enable_if_c<(! boost::is_integral<Func
tor>::value), int>::type) [with Functor = boost::_bi::bind_t<boost::_bi::unspecified, boost::_bi::bind_t<void, void (*)(const boost::shared_ptr<const sensor_msgs::Imu_<std::allocator<void> > >&, const boo
st::shared_ptr<const sensor_msgs::NavSatFix_<std::allocator<void> > >&), boost::_bi::list2<boost::arg<1>, boost::arg<2> > >, boost::_bi::list9<boost::arg<1>, boost::arg<2>, boost::arg<3>, boost::arg<4>, b
oost::arg<5>, boost::arg<6>, boost::arg<7>, boost::arg<8>, boost::arg<9> > >; R = void; T0 = const boost::shared_ptr<const sensor_msgs::NavSatFix_<std::allocator<void> > >&; T1 = const boost::shared_ptr<c
onst sensor_msgs::Imu_<std::allocator<void> > >&; T2 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&; T3 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&; T4 = const boost::shared_p
tr<const message_filters::NullType>&; T5 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&; T6 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&; T7 = const boost::shared_ptr<const mes
sage_filters::NullType>&; T8 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&; typename boost::enable_if_c<(! boost::is_integral<Functor>::value), int>::type = int]’
/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:1072:16:   required from ‘boost::function<R(T0, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8)>::function(Functor, typename boost::enable_if_c<(! boost::is_integral<Func
tor>::value), int>::type) [with Functor = boost::_bi::bind_t<boost::_bi::unspecified, boost::_bi::bind_t<void, void (*)(const boost::shared_ptr<const sensor_msgs::Imu_<std::allocator<void> > >&, const boo
st::shared_ptr<const sensor_msgs::NavSatFix_<std::allocator<void> > >&), boost::_bi::list2<boost::arg<1>, boost::arg<2> > >, boost::_bi::list9<boost::arg<1>, boost::arg<2>, boost::arg<3>, boost::arg<4>, b
oost::arg<5>, boost::arg<6>, boost::arg<7>, boost::arg<8>, boost::arg<9> > >; R = void; T0 = const boost::shared_ptr<const sensor_msgs::NavSatFix_<std::allocator<void> > >&; T1 = const boost::shared_ptr<c
onst sensor_msgs::Imu_<std::allocator<void> > >&; T2 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&; T3 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&; T4 = const boost::shared_p
tr<const message_filters::NullType>&; T5 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&; T6 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&; T7 = const boost::shared_ptr<const mes
sage_filters::NullType>&; T8 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&; typename boost::enable_if_c<(! boost::is_integral<Functor>::value), int>::type = int]’
/opt/ros/kinetic/include/message_filters/signal9.h:281:40:   required from ‘message_filters::Connection message_filters::Signal9<M0, M1, M2, M3, M4, M5, M6, M7, M8>::addCallback(C&) [with C = const boost:
:_bi::bind_t<void, void (*)(const boost::shared_ptr<const sensor_msgs::Imu_<std::allocator<void> > >&, const boost::shared_ptr<const sensor_msgs::NavSatFix_<std::allocator<void> > >&), boost::_bi::list2<b
oost::arg<1>, boost::arg<2> > >; M0 = sensor_msgs::NavSatFix_<std::allocator<void> >; M1 = sensor_msgs::Imu_<std::allocator<void> >; M2 = message_filters::NullType; M3 = message_filters::NullType; M4 = me
ssage_filters::NullType; M5 = message_filters::NullType; M6 = message_filters::NullType; M7 = message_filters::NullType; M8 = message_filters::NullType]’
/opt/ros/kinetic/include/message_filters/synchronizer.h:310:40:   required from ‘message_filters::Connection message_filters::Synchronizer<Policy>::registerCallback(const C&) [with C = boost::_bi::bind_t<
void, void (*)(const boost::shared_ptr<const sensor_msgs::Imu_<std::allocator<void> > >&, const boost::shared_ptr<const sensor_msgs::NavSatFix_<std::allocator<void> > >&), boost::_bi::list2<boost::arg<1>,
 boost::arg<2> > >; Policy = message_filters::sync_policies::ApproximateTime<sensor_msgs::NavSatFix_<std::allocator<void> >, sensor_msgs::Imu_<std::allocator<void> > >]’
/home/pi/ros_ws/src/link/src/roscomm.cpp:231:66:   required from here
/usr/include/boost/bind/bind.hpp:319:35: error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘const boost::shared_ptr<const sensor_msgs::Imu_<std::allocator<void> > >&’ from expression of type ‘const boost
::shared_ptr<const sensor_msgs::NavSatFix_<std::allocator<void> > >’
         unwrapper<F>::unwrap(f, 0)(a[base_type::a1_], a[base_type::a2_]);
         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
link/CMakeFiles/roscomm.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'link/CMakeFiles/roscomm.dir/src/roscomm.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [link/CMakeFiles/roscomm.dir/src/roscomm.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1159: recipe for target 'link/CMakeFiles/roscomm.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [link/CMakeFiles/roscomm.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:138: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j4 -l4" failed
```

I used boost in the following callback statement for approximate time sync:

```
  sync.registerCallback(boost::bind(&navCallback, _1, _2));
```

Can anyone help me with boosting? Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/301051/boost-compilation-error/) by [Old Meme](https://answers.ros.org/users/36982/old-meme/) on ROS Answers with karma: 40 on 2018-08-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Chaos](https://answers.ros.org/users/15091/chaos/) on 2018-08-21**:
Did you add or uncommented `find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS system)` in you CMakeLists.txt file?

**Comment by [Old Meme](https://answers.ros.org/users/36982/old-meme/) on 2018-08-21**:
No, but the same errors came up after I did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Fixed: the actual callback function had the parameters backwards

---

Originally posted by [Old Meme](https://answers.ros.org/users/36982/old-meme/) with karma: 40 on 2018-08-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1